# IBM MQ Message property is null in MDB

Tags: java-8, ibm-mq, java-ee-7, tomee-7, jms2

I am publishing JMS text message to topic and consumer is able to consumer ( MDB ) the text message. But  not able to get Message Object and String property. it is null in MDB consumer side. I have defined MDB in ejb-jar.xml under META-INF folder. I am using

TomEE plus 7.0.2 
JMS 2.0 
IBM MQ 8 
JDK 1.8 
Topic

I refereed below mentioned Tomee official example. In example they used tomee.xml instead i used resource.xml and don't use web.xml

Consumer is MessageDrivenBean

**Consumer is able to get Text or Object Message. But Message property is null**.

> http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-and-webspheremq.html

```
@Resource(name = "qcf") 
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory; 
    @Resource(name = "wmq-javax.jms.Topic") 
    private Topic topic; 
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(); 
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE); 
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(topic); 
    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(); 
    message.setText("Test Message"); 
    message.setObjectProperty("a","b"); 
    message.setStringProperty("c","D"); 
    connection.start(); 
    producer.send(message); 
    session.close(); 
    connection.close();
```

## Consumer

```
<ejb-jar id="ejb-jar_ID" version="3.1"
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">

  <display-name>SampleTransactionMDB</display-name>
  <enterprise-beans>
    <message-driven>
      <display-name>SampleTransactionMDB</display-name>
      <ejb-name>SampleTransactionMDB</ejb-name>
      <ejb-class>com.example.SampleTransactionMDB</ejb-class>
      <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
      <activation-config>
        <activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
          <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property-name>destination</activation-config-property-name>
          <activation-config-property-value>openejb:Resource/projectname/topicname</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property> 
      </activation-config>

        <activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property-name>useJNDI</activation-config-property-name>
          <activation-config-property-value>true</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>

        <activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property-name>HostName</activation-config-property-name>
          <activation-config-property-value>x.x.x.x</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>

        <activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property-name>Port</activation-config-property-name>
          <activation-config-property-value>123</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property-name>QueueManager</activation-config-property-name>
          <activation-config-property-value>xxxxx</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property-name>Channel</activation-config-property-name>
          <activation-config-property-value>xxxx</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property-name>TransportType</activation-config-property-name>
          <activation-config-property-value>CLIENT</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property-name>subscriptionName</activation-config-property-name>
          <activation-config-property-value>xxxxxx</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property-name>sharedSubscription</activation-config-property-name>
          <activation-config-property-value>true</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>


    </message-driven>  
  </enterprise-beans>
  <assembly-descriptor>
  </assembly-descriptor>
</ejb-jar>
```

Guide me why message property is null in MDB consumer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause of the problem. it is my mistake. TopicProxy's **targetClient** should be **JMS**. I wrongly configured as MQ. so I was able to get message but not property.

After changing targetClient value to JMS. I am able to get message and property

**http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-and-webspheremq.html**

Answer (score 0):

> MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);

If you are publishing a message to topic then why are you using a variable named 'queue'?  A topic string generally looks like 'test/ABC/one' (no quotes).

Secondly, why didn't you post the code for the consumer?  Update your original posting to include the consumer code.

Comment: please refer http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-and-webspheremq.html for resource.xml where I am configuring Topic and connection. I used as resource.xml not as tomee.xml

Comment: I tried both ( Topic and Queue ). Message property is null